# Swift 3 remove all blank spaces which are not inside quotes ""?

Tags: regex, swift, string, swift3

What tools does Swift offer to remove only the blank spaces that are not inside the double quotes? ["Alexa", "Siri", "Thomas Marcel"] should be transformed to ["Alexa","Siri","Thomas Marcel"]. I know that you can use "replacingOccurrences", but that would remove the blank space inside the quotes.

Thank you for your help!

edit: thanks to the comments i found out that i just need json serialization!

```
do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: yourArray)
        jsonString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    }
    catch {
    }
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you want to do that. Could this be an XY-problem? How did you obtain the input string? Could it be JSON?

Comment: Easy solution for replacing would be `", "` for `","`. If you need to parse a JSON String just use JSONSerializarion

Comment: Is this for a JSON string? If so, you can deserialse it then reserialise it without the `prettyPrinted` writing option.

Comment: yes its for a json. i select an array of names which are only understood if there are no blanks. how do i reserialise?

Comment: You don't have to remove or replace anything. Just use JSON as it is supposed to be used, with JSON data and you'll be alright. Use JSONSerialization.

Comment: I would suggest that you update the question with information about the *actual* problem. Where does the string come from? What is the string used for? Why do you think that spaces have to be removed? Where does an *array* of names come into place? Who/what does not "understand" it? – And lookup "XY problem" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting JSON do the job for you may be a better plan but, just for fun, you could do something like this:

```
 var line = "[\"Alexa\",         \"Siri\", \"Thomas Marcel\"]"

 line = line.components(separatedBy:"\"")
            .enumerated()
            .map{ ($0 % 2 == 1) ? $1 : $1.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") }
            .joined(separator: "\"")

 // line will contain: ["Alexa","Siri","Thomas Marcel"]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not exactly a regex problem and there should be a better solution using json serialization as per the comment. None the less, as regex is being tagged, therefore the following solution is to check if the problem can be solved in regex way...

You can try this:

```
\s(?=(([^\"]*\"[^\"]*){2})*$)
```

And replace by `""` empty

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GBKSOL/4)

Remember it may lead to Catastrophic backtracking or timeout if each of your strings are too large.... So, if you have to do it only by `regex replace` then I think you can follow this approach... while doing so apply the regex on each line individually rather than providing the full bunch of lines at a time.

Comment: OP actually doesn't need any of this. They need JSONSerialization. See the comments under the question. :)

Comment: I know actually .. it is related to json serialization... but look at the effort ;) just wanted to see, if that can be done... as he wanted :P